# Extracting viewCount & SubscriberCount from YouTube API V3 for a given channel, where channelID does not equal userID

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have a long list of musicians that I need to extract social media information for on a regular basis, including YouTube.  I have populated each musicians' "channel name" as follows:

- ["taylorswift"],
- ["rihanna"],
- ["SiaVEVO"],
- ["AlessoOfficialVEVO"],
- etc

To extract the information I use the following code:

```
for item in list:
yt_user=item[0]
youtube='https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername='+str(yt_user)+'&key=***key***'
youtube2 = urllib2.urlopen(youtube)
tube = json.load(youtube2)
a=str(tube['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'])
b=str(tube['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'])  
out=[a,b]
```

However some musician channel pages do not have a "https://www.youtube.com/user/RihannaVEVO" style URL.  Instead Jack U has the following "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuGozGshjqqErhHGEmHnJw" style.

Apologies if I have missed something very simple but I can't find any way to alter the Channels.List API call when there isn't a Username but only a channelId.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the value in the field "forUsername" pass the channel id in the field "id"